# Upgrade Redhat using Command Line

Tags: rhel, upgrade

I have 5.5 installed on some servers. Now I need to upgrade it to 5.6. I did it by using RedHat 5.6 DVD media using GUI.

But my question is: can this be done without restarting the server and booting from DVD while I'm logged in and the 5.5 session is running? Can this be done on the command line, using the media which I inserted into the DVD drive?

## Action taken based on Matteo Instructions

1. Mounted Redhat media on */media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server*
2. created file in /etc/yum.repos/dvd.repo
3. Then run this command 
   **rpm -ivh createrepo-0.4.blahblahblah.el5.noarch.rpm**
4. Then I tried to run this command
   **createrepo /media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server**

And terminal slapped back with this error

> Error: Only One Directory allowed per run

Normally i copy the RPMs from /media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server to /RPMS directory then i run this command 
createrepo /RPMS 
and it work. So tell me what to do now.

## Action Two

inserted the lines in dvd.repo

```
[dvd.repo]
name=Red Hat Entp Linux $releasever -$basearch - dvd
baseurl=file:///media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

and when I used the command

> Yum clean all

it gave me error

Options Error:  Error Parsing 'file:///media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server/ URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""

Comment: Mods is it possible to move this question to Super User Forum. Because im not getting any reply

Comment: You might have to wait a little bit more than one hour before beginning to complain about missing answers ...

Answer (score 2):

You must backslash spaces in your path to the mounted Red Hat DVD. It must be:

```
createrepo /media/RHEL_5.6\ i386\ DVD/Server
```

instead of yours

```
createrepo /media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server
```

And

```
Options Error: Error Parsing 'file:///media/RHEL_5.6 i386 DVD/Server/ URL must be http, ftp, file or https not ""
```

tells you exactly the same.

Comment: It said Directory /media/RHEL_5.6\ i386\ DVD/Server must be writable. I mounted the ISO image on /media

Comment: Issue the `createrepo` command with the `-o` option and point the `/tmp` dir e. g. to set the output directory (useful for read only media, as `man` page says).

Comment: Ok i did this **createrepo -o /media/Rhel_5.6\ i386\ DVD/Server/** but it said *Must Specify a directory to Index* and open the man page. And i didnt understand this /tmp u mentioned because there is nothing in /tmp and RPMS are on RedHat media

Comment: Please try `createrepo -o /tmp /media/Rhel_5.6\ i386\ DVD/Server/`

Answer (score 1):

Minor releases can be upgraded with the `yum` command:

```
yum upgrade
```

If you want to use the files on DVD you will need to define another local yum repository in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` (e.g., `dvd.repo`):

```
[rhel-cd]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - CD
baseurl=file:///media/RHEL/Server/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Substitute the `baseurl` with the mount point of the DVD

Comment: Dear I have updated the question based on your instructions and found error please have a look. Waiting for ur advice

Comment: I don't have a RedHat DVD at the moment. Are you sure that you need the createrepo command? And in any case you will not be able to run createrepo on a DVD as it is mounted as read-only.

Comment: Dear This time I just did it without initializing RPMS using createrepo and still got error.Please look Action Two

Answer (score 0):

Try mounting your CD/DVD at the mount point like /mount/cdrom, which doesn't contain whitespaces